# Update SnackBar content in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a button that displays a `SnackBar` (or toast) before moving to the next page. I have a countdown and after 5 seconds I push Page2.

```
RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _startTimer();
                      final snackBar = SnackBar(
                        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                        content: Text(
                            'Prepare yourself to start in ${widget._current.toString()}!'), // doesn't work here
                        duration: new Duration(seconds: widget._start),
                        action: SnackBarAction(
                          label: widget._current.toString(), // and neither does here
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Some code to undo the change.
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "I'm ready",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Nothing to see on the countdown but I'll paste it just in case:

```
void _startTimer() {
    CountdownTimer countDownTimer = new CountdownTimer(
      new Duration(seconds: widget._start),
      new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );

    var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
    sub.onData((duration) {
      setState(() {
        widget._current = widget._start - duration.elapsed.inSeconds;
      });
    });

    sub.onDone(() {
      print("Done");
      sub.cancel();
    });
  }
```

So if I display the countdown somewhere else (inside a `Text` for example) it works but it seems that the `SnackBar` doesn't change its contain, it always get the max number of the countdown.

Comment: Are you using stateful widget?  and what is widget._current? Can you share the whole widget code?

Comment: Yes, that widget is a `StatefulWidget`. class ReadyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ReadyPage({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);
  final Map data;
  int _start = 5;
  int _current = 5;

Comment: @Dani how did you achieve this? Is it possible?

Comment: never found the way

Answer (score 3):

you need to implement a custom widget with countdown logic in side for the content field of snackbar, like this:

```dart
class TextWithCountdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final int countValue;
  final VoidCallback? onCountDown;

  const TextWithCountdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.countValue,
    this.onCountDown,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextWithCountdownState createState() => _TextWithCountdownState();
}

class _TextWithCountdownState extends State<TextWithCountdown> {
  late int count = widget.countValue;
  late Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), _timerHandle);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("[$count] " + widget.text),
    );
  }

  void _timerHandle(Timer timer) {
    setState(() {
      count -= 1;
    });
    if (count <= 0) {
      timer.cancel();
      widget.onCountDown?.call();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: not looking into this atm but it looks nice

Comment: Having tested this, I can confirm it works well to set the content of the snackbar.

Answer (score 3):

## Update SnackBar Content

`SnackBar` content can be updated/rebuilt while it's visible by making its `content:` widget dynamic.

In the code sample below we're using a `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder` to dynamically rebuild the content of the `SnackBar` whenever `ValueNotifier` is given a new value.

(There are many ways to to maintain state values & rebuild widgets when it changes, such as RiverPod, GetX, StreamBuilder, etc.  This example uses the Flutter native `ValueListenableBuilder`.)

When running this Flutter page, click the FAB to show the SnackBar, then click on the center text to update the SnackBar's content (multiple times if you like).

#### Example

Use `SnackBarUpdateExample()` widget in your `MaterialApp` `home:` argument to try this example in an emulator or device.

```
class SimpleCount {
  int count = 0;
}

class SnackBarUpdateExample extends StatelessWidget {
  static const _initText = 'Initial text here';

  /// This can be "listened" for changes to trigger rebuilds
  final ValueNotifier<String> snackMsg = ValueNotifier(_initText);
  
  final SimpleCount sc = SimpleCount();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SnackBar Update'),
      ),
      /// ↓ Nested Scaffold not necessary, just prevents FAB being pushed up by SnackBar
      body: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Click FAB to show SnackBar'),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Text('Then...'),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              InkWell(
                child: Text('Click → here ← to update SnackBar'),
                onTap: () {
                  sc.count++;
                  snackMsg.value = "Hey! It changed! ${sc.count}";
                },
              ), /// When snackMsg.value changes, the ValueListenableBuilder
              /// watching this value, will call its builder function again,
              /// and update its SnackBar content widget
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
          onPressed: () => _showSnackBar(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    var _controller = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: SnackContent(snackMsg))
    );

    /// This resets the snackBar content when it's dismissed
    _controller.closed.whenComplete(() {
      snackMsg.value = _initText;
      sc.count = 0;
    });
  }
}

/// The ValueListenableBuilder rebuilds whenever [snackMsg] changes.
class SnackContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<String> snackMsg;

  SnackContent(this.snackMsg);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// ValueListenableBuilder rebuilds whenever snackMsg value changes.
    /// i.e. this "listens" to changes of ValueNotifier "snackMsg".
    /// "msg" in builder below is the value of "snackMsg" ValueNotifier.
    /// We don't use the other builder args for this example so they are
    /// set to _ & __ just for readability.
    return ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
        valueListenable: snackMsg,
        builder: (_, msg, __) => Text(msg));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the snack bar is built once, when the button is clicked. When the state updates, it rebuilds the widget tree according to the changes. The snack bar initially isn't in the widget tree, so it doesn't update.

Try to use stack and show a snack bar, and then you should be able to manipulate it however you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Try to use stack and show a snack bar` what do you mean with that? I create a new Stack like this: new Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Builder(

but nothing changed